# How to show Custom-DropDown options from dropdown outside parent control that has overflow:scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, css

I have a custom dropdown. Its dropdown options gets hidden if the parent control has overflow: scroll, works well if scrolling is removed, but I want scrolling.

plunr demo is here
http://plnkr.co/edit/GvWfJRCZj23NN0J6vTRV?p=preview

```
<table style="height:150px; display: block; overflow:scroll; border-style:solid;border-width:thin">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <td style="width:55px">Sr</td>
       <td>Name</td>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody ng-repeat="x in details" style="max-height:150px">
     <tr>
       <td>{{$index}}</td>
       <td> <angucomplete-alt id="ex1" placeholder="Search countries(local-data)" pause="100" 
          selected-object="selected" local-data="countriestest" enable-Fast-Coding="enableFastCoding"
          search-fields="name,code" title-field="name" minlength="0" 
          input-class="form-control form-control-small"></angucomplete-alt></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

please help.